# UWP Camera API : FocusControl unsupported

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've deployed the UWP sample onto a Win10 tablet, but all of the VideoDeviceController capabilities return unsupported.  I'm most interested in the FocusControl because the autofocus is very, very "slow".  I expect this for a webcam, but the rear camera (SunPlusIT) is 8MP and shouldn't that be a 'real' enough camera to support focus?  Is there a legit reason why this would happen?  I tried updating the driver, but Win10 says it's the latest.

My idea was to manually focus as the button is pressed to see if that is more accurate than just waiting for the autofocus has "settled".  Any other suggestions?  If I hold it completely steady for a few seconds it will work, but my users need to focus/click very quickly.

Comment: What's the version of your Win10? Have you used the latest SDK 14393

Comment: Yes, I have that one.  The tablet vendor offers a custom camera app called XCapture and it seems to focus much quicker than the default camera app.   I emailed them and they said they use "DirectShow" api.  Do you know if that is equivalent to the MediaCapture api for UWP?